# Why some IDEs (Eclipse, VS Code) need to add include paths while gcc manages to compile the same project?

Tags: c++, gcc, include-path

Many of us have struggled with include path problems in their C/C++-IDEs like Eclipse or VS Code. The IDE underlines the #include-directives red and mentions it is unable to find the location of certain headerfiles. But in the same time the project compiles fine via gcc. It is understandable that both are two different steps and pieces of software but why is the gcc able to find the needed include paths while the IDE is not?

Comment: Most IDEs have a build configuration and a parser. The parser is called to highlight code in the editor. The build configuration is used to build the project. They can differ. E.g in Eclipse I have to configure the include paths for my project so that Eclipse can find the dependencies. But for the build I use a Makefile. It contains the build configuration.

Comment: I think you've said it yourself. Compilation and syntax highlighting in an editor are two different processes. If they're not in step then inconsistencies are going to occur.

Comment: OK that helped me in my understanding, thanks guys! Have a wonderful day!

Answer (score 0):

Run `gcc -v -E -` and you'll seen why. Each GCC installation has fixed include paths. GCC can't "find" these headers; GCC relies on being installed correctly.

Note that Visual Studio (the old, non-Code variant) rarely has this problem as it's much better integrated.